# Browser keeps showing transferring data

Tags: php, jquery, performance

I have lots of images on home page says 10,000 images, which are coming from amazon server

i have a code like this

```
<?php
    for($i=0; i <= 10000; i++){
    ?>
    <div class="box">
     <div>title</div>
     <div><img src="amazon seerver url"></div>
     <div>Description</div>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

I want browser doesnot keep processing.. Images may load later

Comment: you can display some images and load more by ajax

Comment: Use one of `image lazy loading` plugins

Answer (score -1):

```
you can show all content and use jquery lazy loading

seee link belwo

       http://jsfiddle.net/5JwUx/7/
```

Comment: yeah for for complete solution i need to know what logic is used to fetch url from amazon

Answer (score -1):

You should try loading only images which are in the browser's visible area. 
You can use lazy load to achieve this.

Try something like jQuery Lazy, simple lazy load implementation using jquery.
[Lazy load](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_basic-usage)

http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/example_basic-usage

Hope this helps.